# How to get all the matching values from an array in react native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

How to get all the matching values from an array in react native?

The array is `Sports = [ "Football", "Tennis", "Volleyball", "Squash", ]`

I tried getting all the matching values by using an if else statement below

```
 useEffect(() => {

        if (((Sports[0] || Sports[1]) || (Sports[2] || Sports[3])) == "Volleyball") { alert('Volleyball') }

        if (((Sports[0] || Sports[1]) || (Sports[2] || Sports[3])) == "Football") { alert('Football') }

        if (((Sports[0] || Sports[1]) || (Sports[2] || Sports[3])) == "Squash") { alert('Squash') }

    }, [Sports])
```

However the code would stops at the first value of the array which means it only runs the code block
`if (((Sports[0] || Sports[1]) || (Sports[2] || Sports[3])) == "Football") {alert('Football') }`

How can this be corrected or is there another way of getting all the matching values from the array?

Comment: What do you mean by *matching values*?

Comment: e.g the array has Squash get the Squash value from the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
((Sports[0] || Sports[1]) || (Sports[2] || Sports[3])) == "Volleyball"
```

Evaluates to:

```
((true) || (true)) == "Volleyball"
```

Which isn't what you want

This is what you wanted:

```
Sports[0] == "Volleyball" || Sports[1] == "Volleyball" || Sports[2] == "Volleyball" || Sports[3] == "Volleyball"
```

But this will be better:

```
Sports.some(sport => sport == "Volleyball")
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing in your code is really misleading, what you want is

### How to find a matching value in an array?

```js
let query = 'Tennis';

let Sports = [ "Football", "Tennis", "Volleyball", "Squash", ];

let result = Sports.find(sportName => sportName == query);
let resultIndex = Sports.findIndex(sportName => sportName == query);

if(result) {
  // query is found and `result` equals the query
}

if(resultIndex != -1){
  // query is found and resultIndex represents its index
}

if(Sports.some(name => name == query)){
 // query is found but we can't know what is its index
}
```

Why your conditions with `if` is ruined?

#### Because the `||` operator is working like a short circuit that choose the first `truthy` value it encounters

so

```js
true || false // => true
2 || true // => 2
```

You see how non-boolean values are converted(coerced) to boolean then evaluated, so

```js
if (
(
(Sports[0] || Sports[1]) || 
(Sports[2] || Sports[3])) == "Volleyball"
) { 
  alert('Volleyball')
}
```

First condition `(Sports[0] || Sports[1])` which is equals to `String || String` and while the first string is truthy(not empty) then the first string is returned which is `Football`, now the second condition is not even evaluated `(Sports[2] || Sports[3])) == "Volleyball"` because the first condition is satisfied and is truthy so it's returned

```
// how these condition can be evaluated 

(Sports[0] || Sports[1]) => 'Football' || 'Tennis'

(Sports[2] || Sports[3])) == "Volleyball" => ('Volleyball' || 'Squash') == 'Volleyball'
```

And what happened when that gigantic condition is converted to one string inside one if?

It's converted to a boolean, so `Boolean('Football') => true` so we always have `if(true)` in the first condition, that's why it always uses that code inside the first `if statement`

And if you're using `react` please don't do such logic in `useEffect` if not necessary.

Check if you can compute the existing of the value in your render function without using an effect and extra state to achieve things that can be computed or derived from your existing data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your condition is correctly written! Perhaps update as:

```
   if (Sports[0] == "Volleyball" || Sports[1] == "Volleyball" || Sports[2] == "Volleyball" || Sports[3] == "Volleyball") // etc...
```

Although that's still a terrible solution!